# Mysql Query to Fetch highest number of votes based on zip code and category

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

In wordpress (custom query are ok) How can I get only 1 post  from each each taxonomy based on zip code and highest number of votes
SO I have 2 custom fields 
1) ZIP CODE (field name zip_code)
2) VOTES    (field name doctor_ratings)

I havent been able to host my databse online so its [here](http://goo.gl/HQq6do)  (only 3 tables)

and I like to retrieve in single query(for speed optimization) all restraunts from all wordpress taxonomies who have maximum votes (votes are like null,1,1.5,2,2.5 (upto 5) so votes are in decimal point here is what I have tried

Other than answer from here only way I have is to loop through all doctors

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS abcde_posts.ID
FROM abcde_posts
INNER JOIN abcde_term_relationships ON ( abcde_posts.ID = abcde_term_relationships.object_id )
INNER JOIN abcde_postmeta ON ( abcde_posts.ID = abcde_postmeta.post_id )
INNER JOIN abcde_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( abcde_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
WHERE 1 =1
AND (
abcde_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
IN ( 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 16, 12, 3, 18 )
)
AND abcde_posts.post_type = 'doctors'
AND (
(
abcde_posts.post_status = 'publish'
)
)
GROUP BY abcde_posts.ID
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Use [`MAX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-maximum-column.html)

Comment: I need to fetch highest from each category id

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't explain much about your use of `postmeta` so I am going to guess how you use it.

For starters, what you need, in pseudo-query-code, is this. You start by getting the highest rating for each zip code.

```
SELECT zip, MAX(rating) AS rating   /*pseudocode*/
  FROM doctors
 GROUP BY zip
```

You then use that query as a subquery to get the doctors' identities and order by zip. You're looking up the doctor that has the rating you found in the zip you found. (If there are two docs tied for highest rating, you get them both).

```
 SELECT d.id, d.name, d.rating, d.zip    /*pseudocode*/
   FROM doctors AS d
   JOIN (
          SELECT zip, MAX(rating) AS rating
            FROM doctors
           GROUP BY zip
        ) AS q ON d.zip = q.zip AND d.rating = q.rating
  ORDER BY d.zip, d.id
```

The problem is this: using `postmeta` is a bit of a pain in the neck. It takes a special query pattern to retrieve meta data in specific columns. You do this for each meta item you need. It makes for elaborate query patterns that look more complex than they are.

```
   SELECT whatever, whatever, 
          zip.meta_value AS zip       
     FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS zip ON wp_posts.ID = zip.post_id AND zip.meta_key='zip_code'
```

That `LEFT JOIN` grabs one meta_key value from postmeta and turns it into a column in your query.

So, you need to do this twice, once for zip and once for rating. With your table names you get this. You should examine the results to ensure you're getting the right information before you proceed.

```
SELECT
  abcde_posts.ID,
  abcde_posts.post_title AS NAME,
  zip.meta_value         AS zip,
  rating.meta_value      AS rating
FROM abcde_posts
  LEFT JOIN abcde_postmeta AS zip
    ON abcde_posts.ID = zip.post_id AND zip.meta_key = 'zip_code'
  LEFT JOIN abcde_postmeta AS rating
    ON abcde_posts.ID = rating.post_id AND rating.meta_key = 'doctor_ratings'
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND abcde_posts.post_type = 'doctors'
  AND abcde_posts.post_status = 'publish'
```

That big mess is your `doctors` table from the pseudocode above.  So you need to use it, gasp, twice, in the query to get what you want.

```
SELECT
  d.id,
  d.name,
  d.rating,
  d.zip 
 FROM (SELECT
        abcde_posts.ID,
        abcde_posts.post_title AS NAME,
        zip.meta_value         AS zip,
        rating.meta_value      AS rating
      FROM abcde_posts
        LEFT JOIN abcde_postmeta AS zip
          ON abcde_posts.ID = zip.post_id AND zip.meta_key = 'zip_code'
        LEFT JOIN abcde_postmeta AS rating
          ON abcde_posts.ID = rating.post_id AND rating.meta_key = 'doctor_ratings'
      WHERE 1 = 1
          AND abcde_posts.post_type = 'doctors'
          AND abcde_posts.post_status = 'publish') AS d
  JOIN (SELECT zip,
               MAX(rating) AS rating
         FROM (SELECT
                abcde_posts.ID,
                abcde_posts.post_title AS NAME,
                zip.meta_value         AS zip,
                rating.meta_value      AS rating
              FROM abcde_posts
              LEFT JOIN abcde_postmeta AS zip
                  ON abcde_posts.ID = zip.post_id AND zip.meta_key = 'zip_code'
                LEFT JOIN abcde_postmeta AS rating
                  ON abcde_posts.ID = rating.post_id AND rating.meta_key = 'doctor_ratings'
              WHERE 1 = 1
                AND abcde_posts.post_type = 'doctors'
                AND abcde_posts.post_status = 'publish') AS doctors
        GROUP BY zip) AS q  ON d.zip = q.zip AND d.rating = q.rating
ORDER BY d.zip, d.id
```

You could, if your hosting service and your WordPress installation allow it, create a `VIEW` defining the `doctors` table. That would make your query more readable: you could use the pseudocode I showed directly.

I hope your eyes don't glaze over too bad. This big query is actually rather simple if you remember that SQL means **Structured** Query Language, and that Structured means you can nest queries inside queries.  It's verbose but simple enough. That's why I started with the pseudocode.